# How to decompress BZ2 directly into Popen stdin in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, popen, bzip2

Scenario: `PCAP` file compressed with `BZIP2` that I would like to parse with `tcpdump` and list the results line by line, within Python 2.7. Here's what I came up with off the top of my head:

```
def tcpdump(filename):
    import subprocess
    import bz2

    p = subprocess.Popen(
        ('tcpdump', '-lnr', '-s', '0', '-'),
        stdin=bz2.BZ2File(filename),
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    try:
        for row in p.stdout:
            yield row.rstrip()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        p.terminate()
```

The problem  with this is that the `stdin` parameter of `Popen` expects an actual file handle and throws this exception:

**AttributeError: 'bz2.BZ2File' object has no attribute 'fileno'**

I could easily make this a 2-step process, but I'd like to avoid an intermediate temporary file.

Thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Quite aside from the bzip2 problem, `Popen(('tcpdump', '-l -n -s 0 -r -'))` is the same as `tcpdump "-l -n -s 0 -r -"`, which wouldn't work on a command line either; you can't pass all your unrelated options in one big single argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two different Popen objects:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['bunzip2', '-c', filename],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(['tcpdump', '-lnr', '-s', '0', '-'],
    stdin=p1.stdout,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()
for row in iter(p2.stdout.readline, b''):
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid `bunzip2` dependency, you could pump the input manually:

```
import subprocess
import threading
from contextlib import closing

p = subprocess.Popen(['tcpdump', '-lnr', '-s', '0', '-'],
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=-1)
threading.Thread(target=pump, args=[filename, p.stdin]).start()
with closing(p.stdout):
     for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
         print line,
p.wait()
```

where `pump()` is:

```
from shutil import copyfileobj

def pump(filename, pipe):
    """Decompress *filename* and write it to *pipe*."""
    with closing(pipe), bz2.BZ2File(filename) as input_file:
         copyfileobj(input_file, pipe)
```